# Help solving $\int \:\frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{9x^2-9x+2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Reading an article online I came across this integral I've been trying to solve since yesterday morning and I literally tried every integration method I know and I still can't solve it. I am a beginner to integrals so help will be appreciated!

I tried substitution, integration by parts and I can't seem to find the correct way!

$$\int \:\frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{9x^2-9x+2}}$$

Does anyone know how to proceed from here? What to do? Because I am clueless. Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth you get a closed-form (long) expression when you plug this into WolframAlpha.

Comment: [Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+dx%2F%28x%2Bsqrt%289x%5E2-9x%2B2%29%29) to the above comment's reference. Are you sure there isn't a typo in your question?

Answer (score 10):

The Euler substitution $\sqrt{9x^2-9x+2} =t+3x$ is better suited here, resulting in $x=\frac{2-t^2}{3(2t+3)} $, $dx=-\frac23 \frac{t^2+3t+2}{(2t+3)^2}dt$
\begin{align}
&\int \:\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{9x^2-9x+2}}dx\\
=& -2 \int \frac{t^2+3t+2}{(2t+3)(2t^2+9t+8)}dt\\
=&-\frac12 \int\left(\frac1{2t+3}+\frac t{2t^2+9t+8} \right)dt\\
=& -\frac14\ln|2t+3| -\frac1{8}\ln| 2t^2+9t+8|+\frac9 {8\sqrt{17}}\ln\bigg|\frac{4t+9-\sqrt{17}}{4t+9+\sqrt{17}} \bigg|
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by the conjugate first to make
$$\int\frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{9x^2-9x+2}}=\int\frac{\sqrt{9 x^2-9 x+2}-x}{8 x^2-9 x+2} \,dx$$
$$I_2=\int\frac{x}{8 x^2-9 x+2} \,dx=\frac 1{16}\int\frac{16x-9+9}{8 x^2-9 x+2} \,dx$$
$$I_2=\frac 1{16}\int\frac{16x-9}{8 x^2-9 x+2} \,dx+\frac 9{16}\int\frac{dx}{8 x^2-9 x+2} $$ The first one is obvious and the second one is simple (if required, use partial fractions).

Now, we are left with
$$I_1=\int\frac{\sqrt{9 x^2-9 x+2}}{8 x^2-9 x+2} \,dx$$ which looks to be much more difficult. However,  partial fraction decomposition, we have
$$\frac 1{8 x^2-9 x+2}=\frac{1}{8 (a-b) (x-a)}-\frac{1}{8 (a-b) (x-b)}$$
and you can find the required integral in the  *"Table of Integrals, Series, and Products"*
(seventh edition) by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik.

The global result will not look very nice.

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

\begin{align}
\int \:\frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{9x^2-9x+2}}
&={\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{9x^2+9x+2}}{8x^2+9x+2}-\dfrac{x}{8x^2+9x+2}\right)\mathrm{d}x \\
{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{9x^2+9x+2}}{8x^2+9x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(3x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}}}{8x^2+9x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{solve for 1st integral} \\
&=\frac12 {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{9\left(2x+1\right)^2-1}}{8x^2+9x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\frac12{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{9u^2-1}}{4u^2+u-1}\,\mathrm{d}u \tag{$u = 2x+1$, $\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{d}u$} \\
&=\frac12 {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\sec^2\left(v\right)-1}\sec\left(v\right)\tan\left(v\right)}{3\left(\frac{4\sec^2\left(v\right)}{9}+\frac{\sec\left(v\right)}{3}-1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v \tag{$u=\dfrac{\sec\left(v\right)}{3}$, $v=\operatorname{arcsec}\left(3u\right), \mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{\sec\left(v\right)\tan\left(v\right)}{3}\,\mathrm{d}v$} \\
&=\frac32 {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sec\left(v\right)\tan^2\left(v\right)}{4\sec^2\left(v\right)+3\sec\left(v\right)-9}\,\mathrm{d}v \\
&=\frac32 {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\frac{\left(\tan^2\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)+1\right) \,\cdot\, 4\tan^2\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)}{\left(1-\tan^2\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\right)^3}}{\left(\frac{4\left(\tan^2\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)+1\right)^2}{\left(1-\tan^2\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\right)^2}+\frac{3\left(\tan^2\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)+1\right)}{1-\tan^2\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)}-9\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v \\
&
\end{align}

Comment: The last integral doesn't seem trivial